# Get-adgroupmember and Displaying nested group name and its members in and exported to CSV file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I found this script online. It was original designed to get all members of one security group and if there are nested group it will write to the host the nested group name and members in hierarchy form.

I tweaked it to import AD security groups from a CSV file and to export the results to CSV with table format. CSV files has two security group with both security groups has nested groups. Script will only list the users in the second security group and it doesn't list the nested security group.

[image]

CSV File format:

```
Groupname     groupad          name
test.testdl office\test.testdl  test.testdl
test.testsg office\test.testsg  test.testsg
```

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$GroupList = @{}

$Table = @()
$Record = @{
    "Name" = ""
    "nested" = ""
    "domain" = ""
    "userName" =""
}

function Get-GroupHierarchy {
    param()

    $searchGroups = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\ad1.csv
    foreach ($item in $searchGroups) {
        $groupMember = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $item.Groupname |
                       Select-Object name, samaccountname, distinguishedName, objectClass
    }
}

foreach ($member in $groupMember) {
    $username = $member.samaccountname
    $distinguishedName = $member.distinguishedName
    $dc = [regex]::Match($distinguishedName,'DC=([^,|$]+)').Groups[1].Value
    $domainuser = '{0}\{1}' -f $dc, $username

    $Record."userName" = $member.samaccountname
    $Record."Name" = $member.name
    $Record."nested" = $member.objectclass
    $Record."Domain" = $domainuser
    $objRecord = New-Object PSObject -Property $Record
    $Table += [array]$objrecord

    if ($member.ObjectClass -eq "group") {
        $GroupList.add($member.name, $member.name)
        Get-GroupHierarchy $member.name
    }

    Get-GroupHierarchy
}

$Table | Export-Csv "C:\temp\SecurityGroups01.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Error message:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The
argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and
then try the command again.
At line:1 char:48
+ $groupMember = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $item.name | Select-Object name, ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Hi, does `$Table` contain anything when you run the script ?

Comment: Hi Sodawillow, When  I run $table I get nothing  but  when I run  $objRecord it return some data

Comment: In the code you posted the function `Get-GroupHierarchy` is defined, but never called.

Comment: thanks Ansgar, I called Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: `$item.Groupname` appears to be empty. Please open your CSV file in a text editor (**not** Excel) and show the unaltered content of that file.

Comment: Thanks Ansfar, I ended up creating the function separately and then I call it in another script and used write to host command

Answer (score 1):

I Know it has been ages since you asked this question. But i was working last week on something similar and obtained some results through some work. I saw this question here working on that piece of work and thought to share my work if it can help somebody.

```
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember 'GroupName'
foreach ($member in $members){
if ($member.objectClass -eq 'Group')
{$NestGroupUsers = Get-ADGroupMember $member | select name, objectclass }
Else {
$hash = [pscustomobject]@{
'name' = $member.name
'objectclass' = $member.objectClass
}
$hash | Export-Csv C:\users.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
}
$NestGroupUsers |Export-Csv C:\users.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```